# Most efficient way to delete multiple key values with localforage?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, localforage

I store data based on unique keys using localforage and the IndexedDB backend. Now I need to **delete** many (but not all) values based on a known array of keys (thousands).

Okay, I can loop through the array and use *removeItem()* for all of them. My first reflex is to do a promise for every action and then utilize *Promise.all()* to wait for all to finish. But I believe this is horrible slow and not efficient(?). The same is for waiting for every single deletion promise to fulfill in serial order.

But is there a more efficient way available, at least for the delete? Like some *removeItem()* with an array of keys that prevents creation and waiting for thousands of promises?

Comment: Store the settings in an object and only store this in localStorage/IndexedDB. Then your delete operations only take one get- and set-Item operation.

Comment: @Andreas I don't understand. It is not settings. I have a few thousand key value pairs and about 15% have to become deleted (depends on what a user does, I have the keys to delete in an array). So putting into one object does not help me?

Comment: Why wouldn't it help? You don't want to modify the storage key by key. So wrap them all in an object and you only have to modify the storage once - when storing the modified object without the deleted keys.

Comment: @Andreas You mean to store ALL data (about 40MB) in one keys value? And only store/update this one object if needed? Interesting idea, but I'm not sure if this is really faster?

Comment: I also wonder if the size of a IndexedDB value is somehow more or different limited than the size of the whole database? For sqlite, this is 1GB (https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html). But this would be enough by far :-)